# Diagonalizing and finding the eigenvalues of matrix of type $T$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I have seen some of the solutions type within the math.stackexchange but didn't able to get the clear idea. Consider here *n* to be $\ge$ 5.
$$ T = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha_1 & \beta & & & \beta\\ \beta & \alpha_2 & \beta & & \\ & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \\ & & \beta & \alpha_{n-1} & \beta \\\beta & & & \beta & \alpha_{n} \end{bmatrix} $$
References will also be helpful. But I tried the some which I didn't understand (already mentioned by you). Giving an example will be worth full.

Comment: have you tried $2\times 2$ matrices of this type to get some idea..?

Comment: @Praphulla. For $ 2 \times 2 $. This matrix will look in this form only when $n\ge 5$. You can try that.

Comment: Even for $4\times 4$. Matrix will be completely filled. For $5\times 5$. You will see this form.

Comment: I do not understand what actually you are saying... What actually do you mean when you say completely filled... Could you please write $4\times 4$ matrix which you are referring to...

Comment: For $4\times 4$$$ T = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha_1 & \beta & 0 & \beta\\ \beta & \alpha_2 & \beta & 0  \\0&\beta &\alpha_3& \beta\\ \beta & 0 & \beta & \alpha_{n-1} \\ \end{bmatrix} $$